# Se puede hacer --publish a AdminLTE?

Tags: laravel, adminlte, artisan, publish

Estoy utilizando AdminLTE en Laravel 10x.
He estado utilizando la plantilla como se muestra en la documentación. Es decir, se utiliza algo así como una instanciación (no sé dónde dice así) al paquete que se encuentra en la carpeta `/vendor`.

He tenido el problema que ya había previsto, y finalmente sucedió cuando clone el repositorio en otra computadora.

El problema es que he agregado algúnas líneas de código en la plantilla original y al actualizar con `composer update` la plantilla queda como nueva, es decir sin las líneas que yo agregué.

He pensando en agregar el paquete a `.gitignore` pero creo que no sería lo más correcto, quiero evitar tener que buscar una mejor opción después...

He buscado a ver si se puede hacer algo como ésto

```
php artisan --publish="VendorName\PackageName\NameServiceProvider
```

No quiero arruinar algo por no saber si funcionará o si lo hago mal.

Jelpmi plys!

Comment: La carpeta vendor NO se debe tocar nunca, precisamente para evitar esas cosas. En su lugar, debes sobreescribir la plantilla correspondiente en tu proyecto, y en la configuración indicar que tu plantilla hereda de la del vendor. No sé exactamente cómo se hace en laravel, hecha un vistazo a temas de Blade en la doc

Comment: Lo entiendo perfecto, lo comenté al principio. Ya sabía que eso sucedería por ser la carpeta de `vendor`. El tema es que me gustaría poder hacer modificaciones al HTML de esta plantilla como para agregar secciones nuevas o desde ahí colocar hojas de estilos o scripts que no quiero tener que colocar en cada una de las instancias. Principalmente me interesa el tema de colocar el favicon personal y otros más. Hay un archivo de configuración pero no sé puede hacer todo desde ahí. Por lo pronto en el proyecto actual creo que ha lo dejaré así.

Comment: Que librería vendor estas usando de adminlte?

Comment: Estoy utilizando "jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.9",